# Conditional Regular Expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex, conditional-statements

I have a conditional regular expression that works on regex test websites, such as regexlib.com, but cannot get it to work in my Java application.

But, http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html indicates that Java doesn't support conditionals, but I've seen other posts on SO imply that it does.

An example of my RegEx is: `(?(?=^[0-9])(317866?)|[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}(317866?))`

It should match either of these inputs: `317866` or `317866A12` or `FCF1CS317866`

How do I work around this Java limitation?

TIA

Comment: Should it match `31786`? If not, what is that `?` doing after the last 6?

Answer (score 11):

Conditional expressions are not supported by [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.
To get around that you could use a 3rd party regexp library such as [JRegex](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

How about just doing this instead?

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})?(317866?)
```

Or if you know that the longer version always start with a letter then you can use this:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5})?(317866?)
```

It will first try to match 6 alphanumerics followed by 31786 or 317866, and if that fails it will then backtrack and try matching 31786 or 317866.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies... I'm not real familiar with RegEx and I didn't realize it could be that simple.  My business rules are: if it starts with an alpha, ignore the first 6, if it starts with a numeric, start the match from the beginning.  So, the second example seems to be more complete.

Comment: @RNeuendorff: The second example should work and it will not match `123456316866`, which the first expression will match. I think you want the second example.

Comment: @Mark Byers: That regex is not completely accurate.  I do not want to match something like "AB1363183A23", but that regex does.

Comment: @RNeuendorff: Are you sure about that? The string you gave as an example doesn't even contain `31786` so how could it match?

Comment: Sorry, I'm working with a couple examples and pasted the wrong string...  Now I'm getting odd results from the Regex Test sites...

Comment: @RNeuendorff: The best test is to write a short Java program to test them. It takes only about 3 or 4 lines of code.