# How to determine syllables in a word by using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Given I have a story. The story consists of words. I need to construct a regular expression to count the number of syllables for each word in a story.

I try to construct a regular expression where the following is met:

```
IF word ends with character 'e'
AND word also contains at least one of the vowel characters 'a'|'e'|'i'|'o'|'u'|'y'
THEN do not match 'e' at the end of word
BUT match all the other vowels in word
```

```
IF word contains only a lone 'e' at the end of a word
AND word does not contain other vowel characters
THEN match the lone 'e'
```

Expected output:

Counting the matches found for each word should result in:

**3** syllables for **ae**r**o**sp**a**ce

**1** syllable for sh**e**

A **total** of **4** syllables.

I was able to construct `(?(?=([a-zA-Z]+e))(?=([aeiouy])))` but need some help from you to get it done in a single expression if that's possible.

Comment: Why match them? Are you extracting, counting, replacing? You have a `aerospace she` string. What is the expected output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a lot about Regex and the use of Regex conditions. Conditionals are not supported by default by the Java Regex package. (Found the answer here: [Conditional Regular Expression in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687921/conditional-regular-expression-in-java))

So, finally constructed a Regex without if-else-then condition.

```
([aeiouyAEIOUY]+[^e.\s])|([aiouyAEIOUY]+\b)|(\b[^aeiouy0-9.']+e\b)
```

(https://regex101.com/r/gPO6mP/17)

Improvements are welcome.

Thanks.